# How to call a app endpoint from within app django

Tags: python, django

Let's say I have a django app that is running on `http://127.0.0.1:8000/`

That app has an endpoint called `homepage` which renders a view and on the view there is a button. When that button is pressed, I want to call an API endpoint (`button_pressed`) within my django app, for example `http://127.0.0.1:8000/button_pressed` (this should return JSON)

Would I have to just do a normal `XMLHttpRequest` to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/button_pressed` in JS when the button is pressed? Or is there another, better way to do it?

Comment: How else would you do it?

Comment: That is what I am asking - so there is no other way?

Comment: Are you asking how to make the asynchronous request?

Comment: Yes, is it any different than a normal request?

Comment: You have to make the request using some javascript on the client, the fetch api is pretty easy to use and is supported by most browsers https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API